# Primefaces breaks when I change HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, jboss6.x

I have a page with Primefaces 5.3 running in a server Jboss 6.4. Also use JSF2.

**With HTTP work well**, but when I change to **HTTPS the css and some images is broken**. sometimes it works and sometimes not, It's random.

In console(Jboss , Browser) not show error.

To add HTTPS, I followed the article.
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/ssl-howto.html